# Query with Increments

Tags: sql, sql-server

How create a SQL query that breaks down active guests for the last 90 days by Age range and gender where age is between 21-25 and then 10 year increments to 75+ and declare age range for easy adjustment?

Comment: Can you share the table structure?

Comment: Also please can you tag whether this is for mssql, oracle, mysql etc.

Comment: yes it is for MSSQL.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use a CASE WHEN like

```
, CASE WHEN table.AGE > 20 and < 26 THEN '21-25'
       WHEN table.AGE > 25 and < 36 THEN '26-35'
       WHEN table.AGE > 35 and < 46 THEN '36-45'
--and so on
       ELSE NULL END AS AGE_GROUP
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing the main issue is of how to get the age ranges (the other conditions should be straight forward). You can define the ranges through a case statement and then group by this column:

```
select CASE 
    WHEN age between 21 and 24 THEN '21..24'
    WHEN age between 25 and 34 THEN '25..34'
    WHEN age between 35 and 44 THEN '35..44'

END as agerange, count(*)
from (select 23 as age
      union
      select 40 as age
      union
      select 41 as age) as ages
group by agerange
```

Result:

```
agerange |count(*)
---------|--------
21..24   |1
35..44   |2
```